# Recovering journal

Tags: 16.04

After starting Ubuntu, I see the following lines. Should I be worried?

```
/dev/sda6: recovering journal
/dev/sda6: clean, 355773/1835008 files, 470404803/7335680 blocks
```

Answer (score 3):

Not usually.

This message normally arises when the computer was not shutdown cleanly and the filesystem is helping you by fixing itself from the journal. So this is often a good thing.

However, if it happens every time, even when you know you've shut it down properly, then it could point to bad things happening on the disk or within the filesystem, in which case you might want to check the disk is not failing or that there's not another hardware issue.

Comment: Ran sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda and the result was

Comment: Ran sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda and the result was

Comment: Ran sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda and the result was Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
Any advice how should I check hardware issues?